# How to solve bundler LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I am using rvm and running Ruby 2.6.1 and using rails 5.2.2. When I try `bundler -v`
I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    2: from /home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    1: from /home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/bundler:23:in `<main>'
/home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/bundler:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/amairu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundler (LoadError)
```

`gem list bundler` returns:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.0.2, default: 1.17.3, 1.17.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
```

It seems that it is trying to look for the file named "bundler" in `/home/amairu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/` folder but there is no such file. The required file is in  a different folder:

`ls /home/amairu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/exe/`

`> bundler`

How can I set it such that the `bundler -v` command looks into the `bundler-1.17.2/exe instead of the bundler-1.17.3/exe`? In other words I need to set the default bundler version as 1.17.2 instead of 1.17.3
I have run:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Which install successfully but still I get an error with bundler -v.
A similar post suggest reinstalling Rails `gem install rails -v 5.2.2` but this did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by uninstalling the bundler with version

```
gem uninstall bundler -v 2.0.2
gem uninstall bundler -v 1.17.3
gem uninstall bundler -v 1.17.2
```

and then check the gem list that bundler has been uninstalled

```
gem list bundler
```

If its  get uninstalled then you can install bundler with version again

```
gem install bundler -v 1.17.2
```

Or if its not uninstalled then might be bundler gem is in your default gemset so you can use the default gemset and then try uninstalling and then install 1.17.2 again

```
rvm gemset use default
gem uninstall bundler -v 2.0.2
gem uninstall bundler -v 1.17.3
gem uninstall bundler -v 1.17.2
gem install bundler -v 1.17.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but just to help anyone that is facing the same problem:

```sh
/home/amairu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@rails522/bin/bundler:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/amairu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundler (LoadError)
```

You have to reinstall **the exact version** that ruby is complying. In the error message above, it was looking for bundler version 1.17.3.

So you should only reinstall this exact version.

```
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
```